# disabling navlink react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router in and I want to disable the to attribute in a certain state. I passed empty string, but that doesn't disable the link instead it takes to the base route of the page. I even tried to pass null but that breaks the code. Is it even possible to do so?

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" to={this.state.role == 4 ? "/pages" : ""}></NavLink>
```

Comment: Try using `"#"`

Comment: It worked :). Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could try disabling the button with a custom click handler.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    const { linkDisabled } = this.state
    if(linkDisabled) e.preventDefault()
}

render() {
    return (
        <NavLink 
            onClick={this.handleClick} 
            className="nav-link" 
            to="/pages"
        >
            ...
        </NavLink>
    )   
}
```

You might want to add some css for when the button is disabled

Alternatively you could just not show the button at all

```
{
    this.state.linkDisabled ? 
        null :
        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/pages"></NavLink>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the same as Stretch0 ,  but i just change to functional component
only my confirmation is disabled
my styled links is the same of NavLink :

NavBar -->  index.js

```
export default function NavBar() {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}
  return (
    <Body>
      <Header>
        <Nav>
          <StyledLink exact activeClassName="current" to="/">
            <MenuLinks>CART</MenuLinks>
          </StyledLink>
          <StyledLink activeClassName="current" to="/payment">
            <MenuLinks>PAYMENT</MenuLinks>
          </StyledLink>
          <StyledLink activeClassName="current"  onClick={handleClick} to="/confirmation">
            <MenuLinks>CONFIRMATION</MenuLinks>
          </StyledLink>
        </Nav>
      </Header>
    </Body>
  )
}
```

NavBar --->  Styles.js

```
export const StyledLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d6d6d6;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  ${(props) => props.disabled && `
  cursor: default;`}
  &.${(props) => props.activeClassName} {
    color: #fe8d3b;
  }
  &:focus,
  &:hover,
  &:visited,
  &:link,
  &:active {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    this.state.role !== 4 ? 
        <a href={false} className="nav-link"></a> :
        <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/pages"></NavLink>
}
```

Comment: React actually throws a warning if you set href to a boolean, but just leaving the href prop unspecified does the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create your custom link wrapper component and to render the `NavLink` or not conditionally. In the following example, the property `active` determines if the link will be rendered or simply the text of the link.

```js
function HeaderLink(props) {
    if(props.active) {
        return <NavLink {...props}>{props.children}</NavLink>
    }

    return <div className='link-disabled'>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Usage with e.g. state dependency within a navigation element:

```
<ul className='main-navigation'>
    <li><HeaderLink to='/'>Personal</HeaderLink></li>
    <li><HeaderLink to='/contact' active={state.personalDataComplete}>Contact</HeaderLink></li>
    <li><HeaderLink to='/signup' active={state.contactDataComplete}>Sigup</HeaderLink></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Stretch0 answer, the tabIndex could also be set to prevent users from tabbing to the link and activating via the keyboard.

A useEffect can be used to blur the link if it becomes disabled while focused.

```
export interface NavLinkButtonProps extends NavLinkProps & {
  disabled?: boolean
}

export const NavLinkButton = forwardRef(function NavLinkButton({disabled, onClick, onKeyDown, children, tabIndex, ...rest}: NavLinkButtonProps,
ref: ForwaredRef<HTMLAnchorElement>
) {
  const linkRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>()
  const mergedRefs = useMergedRefs([ref, linkref])

  useEffect((): void => {disabled && linkRef.current?.blur()}, [disabled])

  return (
    <NavLink
      ref={mergedRefs}
      tabIndex={disabled ? -1 : tabIndex}
      onClick={(e): void => {
        if (disabled) e.preventDefault();
        else onClick?.(e)
      }}
      onKeyDown={(e): void => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter' && disabled) e.preventDefault();
        else onKeyDown?.(e);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NavLink>
  )
})
```